# 2 column bootstrap div - left should be fix on top and right should be scrollable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a layout like this :

[image]

I wrote html like this :

```
<div class="container">
       <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="row">
            <!-- Left side -->
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3">
                <div class="row">
                   <div style="height:400px">
                     container of menu item, which should be fix on top   
                    <div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Right side -->
            <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-">
                <div class="row">
                   <div class="row">
                   <div style="height:900px">
                       Div Scrollable <div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

How could i achieve this ?? please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Bootstrap Affix](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix) may be what you are looking for. It's what the Bootstrap documentation itself uses to keep the menu fixed to the top while the page scrolls.

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible way:

HTML

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="row">
                <!-- Left side -->
                <div class="col-xs-3 clearfix" style="height:400px; background: #f00; position: fixed;">      
                        container of menu item, which should be fix on top   
                </div>                    
                <!-- Right side -->
                <div class="col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-9">
                    <div style="height:900px">
                        Div Scrollable 
                    <div>                            
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[**+Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mrbus1eL/1/)

**EDIT**

I made just simple demo to keep bootstrap padding you need to add one more container inside of left column.